# How to use a specific http port in Traefik v1.7?

Tags: docker, traefik

In order to use sticky session among docker containers, I'm using Traefik v1.7.
But I don't change the http port 80 by a specific port e.g. 8081.

It is okay when I use the port 80 in Traefik in the following way:

```
docker network create mynetwork -d overlay

docker service create --name mynginx --mode replicated --replicas 2 \ 
    --network mynetwork --publish "80:8085" nginx
    
docker service update 
    --label-add "traefik.docker.network=mynetwork" \
    --label-add "traefik.port=8085" \
    --label-add "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/" \
    --label-add "traefik.backend.loadbalancer.stickiness=true" \
    mynginx
    
docker service create 
    --name traefik 
    -p8080:80 -p9090:8080 \
    --mount type=bind,source=/var/run/docker.sock,destination=/var/run/docker.sock \
    --mode=global \
    --network mynetwork \
    traefik \
    --docker \
    --docker.swarmmode \
    --docker.watch \
    --web \
    --loglevel=DEBUG
```

But when I change the port 80 by 8081, Traefik service doesn't work:

```
docker network create mynetwork -d overlay

docker service create --name mynginx --mode replicated --replicas 2 \ 
    --network mynetwork --publish "8081:8085" nginx
    
docker service update 
    --label-add "traefik.docker.network=mynetwork" \
    --label-add "traefik.port=8085" \
    --label-add "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/" \
    --label-add "traefik.backend.loadbalancer.stickiness=true" \
    mynginx
    
docker service create 
    --name traefik 
    -p8080:8081 -p9090:8080 \
    --mount type=bind,source=/var/run/docker.sock,destination=/var/run/docker.sock \
    --mode=global \
    --network mynetwork \
    traefik:v1.7 \
    --docker \
    --docker.swarmmode \
    --docker.watch \
    --web \
    --loglevel=DEBUG
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue in the following way and used Traefik v2.3.
When access the port 80, Traefik will show the service whoami and when access the port 9086, Traefik will show the service mynginximage2.

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.3
    deploy:
      mode: global
    networks:
      - traefik-net
    command:
      #- "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.mynginximage2_ep.address=:8086"
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 9086:8086
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
  whoami:
    image: "traefik/whoami"
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
    networks:
      - traefik-net
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`192.168.0.1`) || Host(`192.168.0.2`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.whoami-service.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
  mynginximage2:
    image: mynginximage2
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
    networks:
      - traefik-net
    #ports:
    #  - 9080:8086
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.mynginximage2.entrypoints=mynginximage2_ep"
      - "traefik.http.routers.mynginximage2.rule=Host(`192.168.0.1`) || Host(`192.168.0.2`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.mynginximage2-service.loadbalancer.server.port=8086"      
networks:
  traefik-net:
    external: true
    name: traefik-net
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't because traefik exposes port 80.

If you type these commands :

```sh
docker pull traefik:v1.7
docker image history traefik:v1.7
```

Output is :

```sh
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
80ab7ee8304c        3 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  LABEL org.opencontainers.…   0B
<missing>           3 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENTRYPOINT ["/traefik"]      0B
<missing>           3 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  VOLUME [/tmp]                0B
<missing>           3 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  EXPOSE 80                    0B
<missing>           3 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:8e3cf7c133ac957e…   75MB
<missing>           8 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:e700a731062c6a113…   1.16MB
<missing>           8 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:c1f4ee36c6a15bdd…   233kB
```

There is an `EXPOSE 80` line that means if you create a container from this image, process are listening on port 80 inside container.

When you use argument `-p 8080:80`, your saying to docker to open port 8080 on host and map it to port 80 inside container. That works because process are listening on port 80 inside !

Otherwise, with `-p 8080:8081`, docker maps 8080 to 8081 inside container and there is nothing to reach with this port because traefik is listening on port 80.

Maybe you want to read traefik through 8081 on host, then use `-p 8081:80`. In all cases, second number must be 80, unless you can change listening port inside container through traefik configuration.